# How to join two MySQL tables in order to determine if user is subscribed to post author?

Tags: mysql

This may be a slightly confusing question. I have a table of user posts with a column Permission that determines who can view the post: 0 = public, 1 = only subscribers, 2 = only contacts.

I have another table "subscriptions" with columns Subscriber_ID and Subscribed_to_ID and yet another table "contacts" with columns User1_ID, and User2_ID.

I don't have much experience with complex MySQL queries, I really usually only need basic queries, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I am looking for a way to select posts from the posts table under these conditions:

1. If the user is neither subscribed nor a contact of the post author, only return public
   posts (those with a Permission of 0)
2. If the user is subscribed to the post author, return posts with either a 0 or 1 
   Permission
3. If the user is a contact (automatically subscribed), return posts with a 0, 1, or 2
   Permission value.

I know the syntax isn't correct, but is this even remotely close to being a good way to do this? Also, I normally only work with one table at a time, so I am confused, do I need to join these three tables?

```
SELECT user_id, 
       * 
FROM   posts 
WHERE  privacy < IF (user_id IN(SELECT * 
                                FROM   contacts 
                                WHERE  user1_id = 'TestUser' 
                                        OR user2_id = 'TestUser'), 2, 
                 IF ( 
                                  user_id IN (SELECT subscribed_to_id 
                                              FROM   subscriptions 
                                              WHERE  subscriber_id = 'TestUser') 
                 , 
                 1, 0) 
                        )
```

Again, I know I'm far off but I'd like to learn some more complex MySQL than the basic stuff I'm used to so if anyone can give me some advice on how to improve this query I'd definitely appreciate it!

Comment: can you create your schema here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

You really need to join these tables.
And, its really easier to not use condition over MySQL, better over PHP.

If I needed to do this, I would do it in this way.

You select post, you join rules, you join suscribers, you join users and then you use PHP for show or not show the message.

Your query is kind of strange.

And join tables is not really complicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly I believe your first requirement could be had like this:

```
SELECT user_id, *
FROM posts P
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions S
ON P.user_id = S.Subscribed_To_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts C
ON C.User1_ID = P.user_id
WHERE S.Subscribed_To_ID IS NULL
AND C.User1_ID IS NULL
AND P.Privacy = 0
```

Could you then create two more SELECT statements and UNION them?

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a function to simplify your life.  You are doing full table queries anyways so optimization isn't an issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts 
WHERE  privacy <= TestPrivacy('TestUser')

CREATE FUNCTION TestPrivacy(CurrentUser VARCHAR(MAX))
BEGIN
DECLARE returnValue INT
   IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM   contacts 
      WHERE  user1_id = CurrentUser
      OR user2_id = CurrentUser) > 0)
   BEGIN
      ReturnValue = 2
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   subscriptions 
          WHERE  subscriber_id = CurrentUser) > 0) THEN
      BEGIN
         returnValue = 1
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         returnValue = 0
      END
   END

   RETURN returnValue
END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
  from posts
 where (privacy = 0) /* public */
    or ( /* suscribers */
            (privacy = 1) 
        and (exists (select 1 
                       from subscriptions 
                      where subscriptions.suscriber_id = 'currentuser' 
                        and subscriptions.Subscribed_to_ID = posts.author_id)
            )
       )
    or ( /* contacts: if the user is a contact, doesn't matter the privacy */ 
        exists (select 1
                  from contacts
                 where (contacts.User1_ID = 'currentuser' and contacts.user2_ID = posts.author_id)
                    or (contacts.user2_ID = 'currentuser' and contacts.user1_id = posts.author_id)
        )
       )
```

I did this based on these assumptions:

- You want to select all the posts a user can see from all authors.
- Your posts table have a column named author_id with the user_id of the post author.
- The user_id of the viewer is known and appears in the query as 'currentuser'
- your contacts table contains only one row per contact pair, thus the double comparison in the where clause

The query was written in the browser, you may encounter syntax errors or other minor issues. Look at the indentation to check proper parenthesis pairing.